# One class with flags or many number of different classes

Tags: python, oop, polymorphism

I have got a dilemma. I am making hundreds of objects of different types. Generally they are going to be `Food` but mostly it'll be specified what type of food it is.

```
class Food(object):
    def __init__(self, taste = None):
        self._taste = taste
class Bread(Food):pass
class Meat(Food):pass
class Soup(Food):pass
```

vs

```
class Food(object):
    def __init__(self, isbread = False, ismeat = False, issoup = False):
        self.is_bread = isbread
        self.is_meat = ismeat
        self.is_soup = issoup
```

Then I am going to compare those objects heavily like if there are two Breads one after another in an array. I would like to know which one is more consistent with 'the art of OOP', which might be more pythonic. Using flags seems faster and easier than calling instances each time comparing two objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using different classes is way more OOP and Pythonic. Using gflags insteads just means storing information about type somewhere other than in the type.

The interesting part now is to work with the type information in a way that makes for readable and clear code as well as good performance. To be honest, I'd ignore the latter in favour of good code until it does become a problem.

Since the only example of working with the type is to compare objects for being the same type, you could most easily do this:

```
type(bread1) == type(bread2)
```

You can also create methods or overload operators to hide the mechanics from most parts of your code, but what's simplest and most readable depends a lot on your actual use cases.

To take another example that you mentioned in the discussion: To compare any breads to be equal, you could do this:

```
class Bread(Food):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Bread)
```

Doing it explicitly like this allows you to have subclasses `Baguette(Bread)` and `Roll(Bread)` whose instances, all being breads, will also compare equal, as will they to any instance of `Bread` itself.

Comment: And what about the case if i would like to know if a single object is Bread, not comparing two of them? Wont flags be a bit clearer than calling isinstance(bread, 'Bread') ?

Comment: No, they wouldn't be cleaner. Using the type to store type information even allows you to distinguish between something being an instance of a given class (`type(bread1) == Bread`) and being an instance of any subclass of it (`isinstance(roll1, Bread)`). If you still have doubts about clean-ness, you should explain what you consider unclean about using the language features that are there for working with types, if what you do is modelling types :-)

Comment: and if i need to check types in some templating engine like Jinja2? If i use flags, setting type directly there is no problem but if am not i need to actually check type twice: 1. when calling constructor and 2. when checking it in a template or anywhere else.

Comment: What do you mean by having to check type when calling a constructor? Having to decide on a type to instantiate? As for having to check it somewhere else in your code – well, if you have a condition on it, you need to check it. Why should checking a flag be easier within regular code? Because it saves some characters of program text? Actually, it's adding complexity: as a Python programmer, you know about types, but you'd have to learn about your flags API. Regarding templates or other syntactic constraints, providing a syntactically primitive API does have merit, though.

Answer (score 0):

***Clearly*** the first option is more pythonic and consistent to OOP.

```
class Food(object):
    def __init__(self, taste = None):
        self._taste = taste
class Bread(Food):pass
class Meat(Food):pass
class Soup(Food):pass
```

This means that all `Soup`, `Meat` and `Bread` objects are `Food`, and have common attributes.
You want, then, to compare if two objects belong to the same subclass of Food. Just use [**`isinstance()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) built-in method, and check if `True`. For example,

```
>>> bread = Bread()
>>> soup = Soup()
>>> isinstance(bread, Soup)
False
>>> isinstance(bread, soup.__class__)
False
>>> isinstance(bread, Bread)
True
```

If you would like to compare objects using `==` operator, just override the `__eq__` (equals) method. Like the following

```
class Food(object):

    def __init__(self, taste = None):
        self._taste = taste

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (isinstance(other, self.__class__)
```

Then you compare objects like this

```
>>> bread1 = Bread()
>>> bread2 = Bread()
>>> soup = Soup()
>>> bread1 == soup
False
>>> bread1 == bread2 #Are both breads?
True
```

Comment: I'd advise against implementing object equality by checking for type equality, unless you deal with singletons. Of course you can define equality any way you like, but for all instances of a type to be considered equal would come as a surprise to the average user of such a class. Also, the way you do it is asymmetric if one of the types involved is a subclass of the other.

Comment: @ThomasLotze However in my case equality means that they are both Breads and just it. They might be a roll and a baguette but both are Bread. So i believe i may implement __eq__ method, right ?

Comment: Of course you may. Just be aware that if you do it by an isinstance check and at some point introduce a class `Roll(Bread)` to collect all instances of different rolls, then `Bread() == Roll()` will hold True but not `Roll() == Bread()` since an instance of a subclass is also an instance of any superclass but not the other way around. I'll update my own answer with an example of how to do it.